# Is it possible to use a C++ library from Rust when the library uses templates (generics)?

Tags: c++, templates, rust, ffi

Is it possible to use a C++ library from Rust when the library (e.g. [Boost](http://www.boost.org)) uses templates (generics)?

Comment: Last I heard, C++ does not have a stable ABI, so you cannot call *any* C++ library from another language. You need to create a C shim, like projects such as LLVM do.

Comment: @Shepmaster “C++ does not have a stable ABI” doesn’t mean that individual compilers don’t provide (maybe even stable) ABIs that support templates. It might be entirely possible to call clang-compiled C++ code from Rust, for instance. For now, `rustc` uses LLVM as the backend so this should in principle be feasible.

Comment: You have a totally different problem: even if you get the ABI problems resolved, rustc couldn't monomorphize a C++ function that isn't already monomorphized by the C++ compiler without invoking the C++ compiler.

Comment: templates works by instancing peices of C++ code with different c++ type/values. You'll literally need a C++ compiler inside your rust compiler and something in between that understands both language so it can translate the code on the fly. Some construct in C++ don't exist in rust (eg, variadic templates) so there is little change of this happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, but it may not be *practical*.

---

The D programming language is one of the very few providing some degree of C++ interoperability; you can read more about it on [dlang](https://dlang.org/spec/cpp_interface.html).

Note the limitation for the template section:

> Note that all instantiations used in D code must be provided by linking to C++ object code or shared libraries containing the instantiations.

which essentially means that you must use C++ code to cause the instantiation of the templates with the right types, and then the D compiler will link against those instantiations.

---

You could do the same for Rust. Without compiler support, this means mangling the names manually. In the FFI section, you will find the [link attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#linking):

```
#[link(name = "snappy")]
extern {
    fn snappy_max_compressed_length(source_length: size_t) -> size_t;
}
```

which tells the compiler which linked library will provide the symbol, you will also support for [various calling conventions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#foreign-calling-conventions) and the [no_mangle attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#calling-rust-code-from-c).

You may need to apply `#[allow(non_snake_case)]` as appropriate.

---

*Servo uses [bindgen](https://crates.io/crates/bindgen) to generate Rust bindings for C and C++ code; I am unclear on the level of C++ support, and somewhat doubtful that it can handle templates.*