# How to create and return a C++ struct from Rust FFI?

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm trying to create and return a C++ struct. I am currently getting a `cannot move out of dereference of raw pointer` error when I try to compile. Any idea how I can make this work?

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]
#![allow(unused_variables)]

extern crate octh;

// https://thefullsnack.com/en/string-ffi-rust.html
use std::ffi::CString;

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn Ghelloworld(
    shl: *const octh::root::octave::dynamic_library,
    relative: bool,
) -> *mut octh::root::octave_dld_function {
    let name = CString::new("helloworld").unwrap();
    let pname = name.as_ptr() as *const octh::root::std::string;
    std::mem::forget(pname);

    let doc = CString::new("Hello World Help String").unwrap();
    let pdoc = doc.as_ptr() as *const octh::root::std::string;
    std::mem::forget(pdoc);

    return octh::root::octave_dld_function_create(Some(Fhelloworld), shl, pname, pdoc);
}

pub unsafe extern "C" fn Fhelloworld(
    args: *const octh::root::octave_value_list,
    nargout: ::std::os::raw::c_int,
) -> octh::root::octave_value_list {
    let list: *mut octh::root::octave_value_list = ::std::ptr::null_mut();
    octh::root::octave_value_list_new(list);
    std::mem::forget(list);
    return *list;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> I'm trying to create and return a C++ struct

You cannot; C++ (like Rust) does not have a stable, defined ABI. There is no way in Rust to specify that a structure has `repr(C++)`, therefore you cannot create such a structure, much less return it.

The only stable ABI is the one presented by C. You *can* define structs as `repr(C)` to be able to return them directly:

```
extern crate libc;

use std::ptr;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct ValueList {
    id: libc::int32_t,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello_world() -> ValueList {
    let list_ptr = ::std::ptr::null_mut();
    // untested, will cause segfault unless list_ptr is set
    unsafe { ptr::read(list_ptr) }
}
```

That method is highly suspicious though; normally you'd see it as

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello_world() -> ValueList {
    unsafe {
        let mut list = mem::uninitialized();
        list_initialize(&mut list);
        list
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Is it possible to use a C++ library from Rust when the library uses templates (generics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43660931/155423)

---

I encourage you to read my [Rust FFI Omnibus](https://github.com/shepmaster/rust-ffi-omnibus/).

Comment: Note: C++ *also* has a C FFI, and therefore any C++ class/struct compatible with its C counterpart would be usable from Rust like it is from C.

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster. It now compiles. It may be working, but my Octave helloworld isn't yet, so I'm not 100% sure. https://github.com/ctaggart/octh_examples/blob/master/src/lib.rs

Comment: @CameronTaggart Not sure, but you should prevent name mangling on all functions. Isn't a `#[no_mangle]` missing in `Fhelloworld`?

Comment: @E_net4 I just tried adding it, but no luck. I get the same error. https://github.com/ctaggart/octh_examples/issues/2